# File types in dropdown in open file dialog

Tags: html, file-upload, input, openfiledialog

I am using the HTML `input type="file"` on my webpage. I specify several types of file in the "accept" attribute, but when the Open File dialog appears, the file type dropdown only has the choices "All Files" and "Custom Type" instead of the types I specified. How do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<input name="sample" type="file" runat="server" id="sample"
     accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,application/pdf,application/msword" />
```

Here is a picture to illustrate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Google Chrome based on your screenshots. Unfortunately, you are not able to change this as it is browser-implemented, and have nothing to do with HTML or scripting.